# Is it possible to dynamically add element in browser PDF viewer

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-objects, dom-events

While open the PDF  in a browser, have to add font-icons and set some actions.

I have open the PDF inside the iframe in browser, there are 3 icons on the top  of the paper-toolbar.

1) Rotate 2) Print 3) Download.

Need to add one more element. Is it possible to do it in Javascript?

```
<html>
<head>
 <link href=" https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="myFrame" style="display:none" width="600" height="300">
 <i class="fa fa-bell" >Hello</i>
<button type="button" >Hellos</button>

    </iframe>
<input type="button" value="Open PDF" onclick = "openPdf()"/>
<input type="button" value="Open PDF1" onclick = "openPdf1()"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openPdf()
{
var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
omyFrame.style.display="block";
omyFrame.src = "AngularJS-Brad-Green-Shyam-Seshadri(www.ebook-dl.com).pdf";
document.getElementById("myFrame").className = "fa fa-bell";

   var btn = document.createElement("button");  
    var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);



}

function openPdf1()
{
var omyFrame = document.getElementById("myFrame");
omyFrame.style.display="block";
omyFrame.src = "dummy_pdf.pdf";
}

</script>
</body>
```

Nothing works. [image]
[image]

Comment: I've play a bit with the plugin. Was not able to access toolbar without  opening it in chrome dev tools first. You may try using something like: http://viewerjs.org/ as an alternative.

Comment: @Vladimir M So there is no way to edit or overrides the features of browser built-in plugins via javascript right?if i disable the browser plugins programatically  and use viewerjs and add the element there means it will work out?

Comment: this particular plugin is using shadow DOM to render its  sub-components. It is not possible to access those from external javascript. viewerjs does not hide its internals, so it is possible to alter its contents.